# Best Spanish translation for “Visit Google Maps for [address]”

Tags: traducción

What’s the best Spanish translation for “Visit Google Maps for *[address]*” or “Look up *[address]* on Google Maps”? (Of course, *[address]* is supposed to be replaced by any street address.)

If it helps, in French I’ve been told to use “Voyez *[address]* sur Google Maps”.

According to Google Translate, this would work:

> Ver [address] en Google Maps

Is this correct or does it sound weird to a native Spanish speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ver [address] en Google Maps" > Sounds to me like "Me: Tarzán, you Cheeta" speak. Like an automatic translation.

I will translate as:

> Visita Google Maps para ver la [adress].

or:

> <strike>Mira</strike> Busca la [adress] en Google Maps.

**Why the use of definite article "la"?**
Because "street" is feminine singular in spanish. Depends type of street (avenue, road, square) or place (town, village, gardens, etc.) we use one or another. Here's some examples:

- Street > La calle
- Avenue > La avenida
- Road > La carretera
- Square / Plaza > La plaza
- Boulevard > El Bulevar
- Alley > El callejón
- Gardens > Los jardines

EDIT: Thanks to DeStrangis for suggest "Buscar" instead of "Ver"!

Comment: Thanks for confirming my doubts, providing a proper translation, and explaining the difference. I would upvote this twice if I could.

Comment: What about omitting the article ‘la’? I.e. `Mira [address] en Google Maps`. I imagine that sounds weird, too?

Comment: Even though it's true that "Ver [dirección] en Google Maps" sounds like _telegram speak_ it would not be out of place on a web page and this alternative may be too wordy. It all depends on how the rest of the text is written and where the link to Google maps occurs.

Comment: @DeStrangis Well, I’m displaying a small Google Maps embed on the web page, and below it I use the text to link to the full/bigger map on Google Maps. Would it feel out of place then?

Comment: In addition, use of 'la' only works for an address in Spanish. For all we know, the OP may be translating how to find an address somewhere else. How do _"la 16 oak avenue"_ or _"el EC1V 7DP"_ (common in the UK) sound to you?

Comment: @MathiasBynens There are other options as well. How about "Buscar en Google Maps"?, also "Localizar" or even "Ubicar" work better than "Ver" which does sound like Tarzan. Personally I'd go with "Buscar", but this in no way invalidates Arkana's answer.

Comment: @DeStrangis Yes, you're right! I will edit the answer. Thanks! "Buscar" sounds so much better. Also, "la 16 oak avenue" sounds weird, but "la avenida oak 16" sounds good.

Comment: I disagree.  The use of an infinitive instead of an imperative is widespread in Spanish signage.  It doesn't come across as Tarzan speak at all in that context.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am a native speaker and `Ver [address] en Google Maps` doesn’t sound weird to me. Even though some native speakers may be really strict on this, they would understand the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The best spanish translation is:

> Busca en Google Maps la [address].